# How do I get get_page_template_slug() without the .php file extension with wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically what Im trying to do is

```
wp_enqueue_style('pageStyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/' . get_page_template_slug() . '.css', array(), null, 'all');
```

which works fine, but it outputs `template.php.css` how do I make it so that it's `template.css` instead?

Comment: can't you just use `basename()`

Comment: like `basename("/etc/whatever.php", ".php");` will return `whatever`

Comment: So `basename(get_page_template_slug(), ".php");`should suffice for your needs

Comment: @Stender yeah I could just use that, I was just wondering if Wordpress has a specific hook for it.

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
str_replace(".php","",get_page_template_slug())
```

So your code will become -

```
wp_enqueue_style('pageStyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/' . str_replace(".php","",get_page_template_slug()) . '.css', array(), null, 'all');
```

Comment: So I have to do it like that? I was hoping there was a specific hook for it.

Comment: This is the easiest way to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can cut out the extension in your case, assuming this is what you want:

```
pathinfo($file_path)['filename']
```

Will give you the file name of `template.php` without the extension (i.e. `template`).

Complete line (assuming PHP 7+):

```
wp_enqueue_style('pageStyle', pathinfo(get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/' . get_page_template_slug())['filename'] . '.css', array(), null, 'all');
```

Comment: Im not sure if Im doing it right, but this doesnt seem to work.

Comment: I have added the complete line, see if it works for you. If you're using PHP 5, try to separate the function call from the array element access (so it will be 2 lines): $path = pathinfo([path]), $result = $path['filename'].